# Linux (ubuntu): copying directory to another directory which does not exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, copy, cp

I am going through linux tutorial, and in it is written that `cp -r dir1 dir2` will copy directory `dir1` into `dir2`, and if `dir2` does not exist then `dir2` will be created and then `dir1` will be copied to `dir2`.

However when I try in my ubuntu 12.04 system this is not happening.

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ ls | grep dir
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ mkdir dir1
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ ls | grep dir
dir1
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ cp -r dir1 dir2
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ ls | grep dir
dir1
dir2
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ ls ./dir2
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

So you see that although `dir2` is created, it is empty. Confirming this below.

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ cd dir2
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~/dir2$ ls
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~/dir2$
```

Could someone tell me if this is expected or something is going wrong ? Why is `dir1` not copied to `dir2` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please request migration to a more appropriate site, either unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Comment: The directory you copied was empty. So the copy is also empty.

Comment: @Barmar How to we migrate this question to unix.stackexchange ? Also, however, I tried by making a file inside dir1 and copied to dir2. Now dir2 shows that file. My initial impression was that `dir1` will be copied to `dir2`. But now I get to see "contents of `dir1` will be copied to `dir2`". So in my OP the "contents" of `dir1` was empty so nothing was copied to dir2. Thanks. Actually this question can be closed now.

Comment: Click on `flag` and request that the moderators move it.

Comment: If `dir2` already exists, `cp dir1 dir2` will create `dir2/dir1` and that will be a copy of the original `dir1`. If `dir2` does not yet exist, it will create `dir2`, and that will be a copy of the original `dir1`.

Comment: This is the same logic as `cp file dir2`.